# How do I change a group of group IDs in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a large /etc/group. All GIDs between 100 - 999 I want to change them by adding a 9 to the beginning of it and all other group IDs I want to leave alone. 
Ex.

```
group1:x:12:
group2:x:123:
group3:x:234:
group4:x:678:
group5:x:1234:
```

Should become.

```
group1:x:12:
group2:x:9123:
group3:x:9234:
group4:x:9678:
group5:x:1234:
```

I've tried to do this with awk and sed but some things are not clear to me how to do. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Something like `sed 's/:(\d\d\d):/9\1/' /etc/group > group.new`

Comment: If you try to do this and you don't know **exactly** what you're doing, I think you're gonna have a bad time: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33844/change-gid-of-a-specific-group

Comment: Bishop - Thank you for posting. When I ran your code, I got this: `code` sed: -e expression #1, char 17: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS                                                                                                                                                           ---   I may have messed it up tho. Not sure how.

Comment: @ Two-Bit Alchemist  - Thanks for the link. I'm still reading it but I need to find all the "gotchas" BEFOR I do this thing for real  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $3>=100 && $3<=999 {$3="9"$3} 1' file
group1:x:12:
group2:x:9123:
group3:x:9234:
group4:x:9678:
group5:x:1234:
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/:([0-9]{3}:[^:]*$)/:9\1/' file
```

Output:

```
group1:x:12:
group2:x:9123:
group3:x:9234:
group4:x:9678:
group5:x:1234:
```